# Is there any way to use the old permission mode but compile with SDK 23?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

The problem is that we have not time to properly support the new permissison mode yet.

Comment: No if you want to target Android 6.0

Comment: @NikoYuwono any hack avaiable?

Comment: No that I know, and I don't think it's a good way to force it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can keep your compile SDK veersion as 23 but the target SDK version must be lower than 23 to use older permission model.